# Only apply style to visible table columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a table on which I apply CSS to all columns so that it looks like a grid:

[image]

Under certain conditions, some of those columns needs to be hidden:

[image]

The style I'm applying looks like this (add border-left to each column except for the first column):

```
 td.nowrap {
    white-space:nowrap;
  }

  table.table td:nth-child(1n + 2), table.table thead th:nth-child(1n + 2), table.table tfoot th:nth-child(1n + 2) {
    border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
  }

  .table .text-center {
    text-align: center
  }
```

Once I hide the first column, the border-left is applied and I get an extra thick line on the left:

[image]

Is there a way to only apply `td:nth-child(1n + 2)` to visible columns which doesn't have an attribute of `disabled`?

```
<td ..... hidden>_____</td>
```

I'm currently trying to use the `:not` pseudo class without any luck:

```
table.table td:not([hidden]):nth-child(1n + 2), table.table thead th:not([hidden]):nth-child(1n + 2), table.table tfoot th:not([hidden]):nth-child(1n + 2) {
    border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
  }
```

JSFiddle to show the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/w2jnqht3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is special pseudo-class `:not()` in CSS.

   https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/

   You could use it in that way:

   ```css
       td:nth-child(1n + 2):not([hidden])
       {
           background-color: red;
       }
   ```

   ```html
   <table>
     <tr>
       <td>Cell</td>
       <td hidden>Cell with hidden attribute</td>
       <td>Cell</td>
       <td hidden>Cell with hidden attribute</td>
       <td>Cell</td>
       <td hidden>Cell with hidden attribute</td>
       <td hidden>Cell with hidden attribute</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
   ```
2. But your case is actually is about another issue.
   If you need to hide left border of the first cell in a row (considering that there could be hidden cells in a row) you could do it in more simpler way.
   As you are using `bootstrap`, you need to take it in mind.

```css
th
{
  width: 50px; /* Just for better appearence */
}


table
{
    border-collapse: collapse; /* Cell border will collapse */
    border: none; /* Remove border of the table */
}

.table > thead > tr > th /* Selector with the same  specificity as bootstrap has about <th> elements */
{
    border: 2px solid green; /* All borders are green */
    border-top: none; /* Remove top border */
    background-color: red;
}

.table > thead > tr > th:first-child, /* The same specificity and very first cell */
.table > thead > tr > th[hidden] + th /* The same specificity and a cell after hidden cell (first visible) */
{
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-left: none;
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table lot-goods-list table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="sortable text-center" hidden>A</th>
                <th class="sortable text-center">B</th>
                <th class="sortable text-center">C</th>
                <th class="sortable text-center">D</th>
                <th class="sortable text-center">E</th>
                <th class="sortable text-center">F</th>
                <th class="actions border left column-squash"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>

                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table lot-goods-list table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="sortable text-center">B</th>
                <th class="sortable text-center">C</th>
                <th class="sortable text-center">D</th>
                <th class="sortable text-center">E</th>
                <th class="sortable text-center">F</th>
                <th class="actions border left column-squash"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>

                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm trying the :not pseudo-class and it's not doing anything, doesn't matter if I put it directly after td or after nth-child:

`table.table td:not([hidden]):nth-child(1n + 2), table.table thead h:not([hidden]):nth-child(1n + 2), table.table tfoot th:not([hidden]):nth-child(1n + 2) `

Comment: You modified you question and it became inconsistent. What particular HTML attribute you need to use in CSS selector: `hidden` or `disabled`?

Comment: Apologies, it's `hidden` I'm looking for, typed the wrong attribute in the `td` tag in my question.

Comment: I think you're close, just can't get it to work in my JSFiddle, maybe bootstrap is interfering? https://jsfiddle.net/w2jnqht3/

Comment: As show in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w2jnqht3/
As soon as I delete column A, it works perfectly, adding a class or attribute of hidden and column A goes away, but column B is still filled with red and still has a green left border.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93296/discussion-between-vladimir-serykh-and-jan-vladimir-mostert).